# Intuition behind the Geometric Mean of a set of data points $a_i$

Tags: sequences-and-series, means

The arithmetic mean of two numbers makes sense, it is just the "middle". The arithmetic mean of a set of data points $a_i$ makes sense [sort of] and is called the average (or sometimes mean). What about the geometric mean?

I tried to make sense of it but could find nothing. I convinced myself in the case of geometric mean of two numbers as follows:

It is that number which when inserted between two numbers, together forms a geometric progression [and the geometric progression is quite a useful thing].

But, what about the geometric mean of a set of points $a_i$? What does the number $(a_1 . a_2  \ldots  a_n)^{1/n}$ mean for the set of numbers $a_i$ ?

Comment: the geometric mean is $(a_1\cdot a_2 \cdots a_n)^{1/n}$. What you describe is some mixture of a harmonic mean $(\frac 1 {a_1} + \frac 1 {a_2} + \cdots \frac 1 {a_n})^{1/n}$ and arithmetic

Comment: Or rather the harmonic mean of the reciprocals $\{\frac 1 {a_1} , \cdots \}$

Comment: @mathreadler Sry I don't know what got into me!! Just a little too excited, I guess.

Comment: Yes that happens to me too once in a while. :)

Comment: I'm not sure if the difference of find is between (taking the geometric mean) of "a number" vs "a data point", or rather between "a number" vs "several numbers" ?

Comment: @leonbloy "2 Numbers" vs "Several Numbers". Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Rahul All interpretations you mention are wonderful, but is there a more abstract, intuitive and more fundamental explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One observation is that the geometric mean is the same as the arithmetic mean if we take the logarithms of the values.

$$LOG(GM(X_i)) = AM(LOG(X_I))$$

The geometric mean is more natural/appropiate when it's more natural/appropiate to multiply the values (hence, sum the logarithms) instead of summing the values. (Also , the values should be inherently positive). (See for example [here](http://ocw.jhsph.edu/courses/MethodsInBiostatisticsI/PDFs/lecture14.pdf))

For example, if the inflation rate of some year was $R_i$, that means the prices increased by a *multiplicative factor* $F_i = 1+R_i$. We see that the accumulated effect of several years is obtained by multiplying these (inherently positive... even when we have deflation) factors; it makes total sense to multiply them, it makes little or no sense to sum them. Then, to compute an average increase for a sequence of years, one should compute $\overline F=(\prod 
 Fi)^{1/n}$  (and from that the "average inflation rate" as $\overline R=\overline F -1$). That average has a concrete meaning: if all the years we'd have the same constant price increase $\overline F$, then the total increase would have been the same.

Answer (score 0):

One interpretation of a geometric mean is a kind of an average of probabilities of a sequence of independent events occurring. But this only makes sense if the $a_k \in [0,1]$ of course.

---

Take for example the average probability of an event among six dice rolls to get a 6 is $$(1/6 \cdot 1/6\cdot 1/6\cdot 1/6\cdot 1/6\cdot 1/6)^{1/6} = 1/6$$, the same as the probability for having one 6 rolled on one dice.

Comment: No problem. Please elaborate.

Comment: Nice interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Also,
the geometric mean is 
the limit of the power mean
in the sense that,
if all $a_i > 0$,
$\left(\prod_{i=1}^n a_i\right)^{1/n}
=\lim_{p \to 0} \left(\frac1{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^p\right)^{1/p}
$.